# Android: Applying same animation to different buttons

Tags: android, animation, button

I have 20 buttons in the screen of which if the user pressing the correct button correctly, a score will be shown by animating from the button. Same for pressing the wrong button and showing a negative message.

### Animation.xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="-5%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="-15%p" />
```

### popup_message method

```
public void show_pop_message(int pop_message, int x, int y)
{
    final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.overall_frame);

    final TextView tv;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(""+pop_message);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(0x7C5B77);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    if(pop_message > 0)
    {
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));    
    }
    else
    {
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bright_red));
    }
    tv.setTextSize(Constant.SIZE.FONTSIZE_BIG);
    params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y;
    rl.addView(tv, params);     

    // set animations 
    fade_out_move_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Game.this, R.anim.fade_out_move_up);
    fade_out_move_up.setAnimationListener((new AnimationListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            rl.removeView(tv);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }
    }));
    tv.startAnimation(fade_out_move_up);
}
```

### Logcat:

```
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.abc. abc /com. abc. abc.Game}
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com. abc. abc /com. abc. abc.Game}
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3345)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3432)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:164)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5377)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-25 11:48:27.113: E/ActivityThread(22376):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 11:48:27.183: D/AbsListView(22376): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-25 11:48:27.203: D/AbsListView(22376): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-25 11:48:28.123: I/System.out(22376): pool-1-thread-1 calls detatch()
05-25 11:48:28.173: I/System.out(22376): pool-1-thread-2 calls detatch()
05-25 11:48:28.473: D/ProgressBar(22376): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-25 11:48:28.473: D/ProgressBar(22376): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-25 11:48:28.473: D/ProgressBar(22376): updateDrawableBounds: right = 1536
05-25 11:48:28.473: D/ProgressBar(22376): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 61
05-25 11:48:28.473: D/ProgressBar(22376): updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
05-25 11:48:28.543: D/AbsListView(22376): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-25 11:48:29.063: D/AbsListView(22376): onDetachedFromWindow
05-25 11:48:29.713: E/ViewRootImpl(22376): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-25 11:48:30.413: W/System.err(22376): [DEBUG] GbaRequest - GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent null
05-25 11:48:30.413: W/System.err(22376): [DEBUG] NafRequest - NafRequest: NafRequest constructor===useragent null
05-25 11:48:30.823: I/System.out(22376): Thread-8463 calls detatch()
05-25 11:48:32.373: I/System.out(22376): Thread-8463 calls detatch()
05-25 11:48:35.383: W/System.err(22376): [DEBUG] GbaRequest - GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent null
05-25 11:48:35.383: W/System.err(22376): [DEBUG] NafRequest - NafRequest: NafRequest constructor===useragent null
05-25 11:48:35.723: I/System.out(22376): Thread-8465 calls detatch()
05-25 11:48:36.573: D/AndroidRuntime(22376): Shutting down VM
05-25 11:48:36.573: W/dalvikvm(22376): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41728da0)
```

### Question:

The popup_message scores can be shown correctly for each of the button press. However, after the first button is pressed, if the user presses the second button, button1's pop up message will be animated again together with button2. Same for the remaining button presses on other buttons: all buttons' animating performing at the same time.

I do not want the message reappear again after animation.

What is the problem of the above and how could this be modified? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The animation is running, effectively setting alpha to , but the button is still there inside `r1`.

You probably want to put on your animation listener, `animetionEnd` something like:

```
rl.removeView(tv);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have added the `removeView` in `onAnimationEnd`, but it invokes a `RunTimeError` as shown in the question.